# Mongoid - Updating Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

From the mongoid docs:

> Consider a member that has a number of posts:
>
> class Member   include Mongoid::Document   has_many :posts
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts end
>
> You can now set or update attributes on an associated post model
>   through the attribute hash.
>
> For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be
>   instantiated, unless the hash also contains a _destroy key that
>   evaluates to true.
>
> params = { member: {   name: "joe", posts_attributes: [
>       { title: "Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!" },
>       { title: "The egalitarian assumption..." },
>       { title: "", _destroy: "1" } # this will be ignored   ] }}
>
> member = Member.create(params['member']) member.posts.length # => 2
>   member.posts.first.title # => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation
>   browser!' member.posts.second.title # => 'The egalitarian
>   assumption...'

Is there a way to update nested attributes instead of **creating** them?

Comment: can you post your schema, it should be simpler to answer.

Comment: It's a really large schema, I'll cut it down and post it.

Comment: Any chance you could post the schema or did you get this solved myxospsm?

Comment: I did not solve this yet. I don't have a schema, I was just curious. Say I have a post and comments, how do I update the comments from the post and not just create them?

Answer (score 1):

It relies on the nested documents having IDs.

In a Rails form, for instance, the corresponding attributes fields (in your case, `posts_attributes`) will be passed as part of the form.  Rails then does an update for elements *with* an ID, and a create for those *without* an ID.